# Slice doesn't seems work in array of functions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this function:

```
function UIAlerts() {}
```

Then i associate a variable into this function using prototype methodology:

```
UIAlerts.prototype.questions = []
```

After, I push one function to this array:

```
UIAlerts.prototype.questions.push(function(){
     //do stuff
});
```

After a click event is executed the following code:

```
if (UIAlerts.prototype.questions && UIAlerts.prototype.questions.length > 0) {
        UIAlerts.prototype.questions.slice(0, 1);
        UIAlerts.prototype.questions[0] && UIAlerts.prototype.questions[0]();
}

if (UIAlerts.prototype.questions.length == 0)
    UIAlerts.prototype.questions = undefined;
```

The problem is that the slice doesn't remove the first possion of the array of function. Any Idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`slice` doesn't modify an array, it returns a copy of that section.

You're looking for `Array.prototype.splice`.